# How do I decode zlib stream in Go?

Tags: go, zlib

### What is the issue?

I cannot decode valid compressed chunks from zlib stream using go's `zlib` package.

I have prepared a github repo which contains code and data illustrating the issue I have: https://github.com/andreyst/zlib-issue.

### What are those chunks?

They are messages generated by a text game server (MUD). This game server send compressed stream of messages in multiple chunks, first of which contains zlib header and others do not.

I have captured two chunks (first and second) with a proxy called "mcclient", which is a sidecar to provide compression for MUD clients that do not support compression. It is written in C and uses C `zlib` library to decode compressed chunks.

Chunks are contained in "chunks" directory and are numerated `0` and `1`. `*.in` files contain compressed data. `*.out` contain uncompressed data captured from mcclient. `*.log` contain status of zlib decompression (return code of `inflate` call).

A special `all.in` chunk is chunk `0` concatenated with chunk `1`.

### Why do I think they are valid?

1. `mcclient` successfully decompresses input chunks with C's `zlib` without any issues. `*.log` status shows `0` which means Z_OK which means no errors in zlib parlance.
2. `zlib-flate -uncompress < chunks/all.in` works without any errors under Linux and decompresses to same content. Under Mac OS it also decompresses to same content, but with warning `zlib-flate: WARNING: zlib code -5, msg = input stream is complete but output may still be valid` — which look as expected because chunks do not contain "official" stream end.
3. Python code in `decompress.py` correctly decompresses with both `all.in` and `0`/`1` chunks without any issues.

### What is the issue with go's zlib?

See `main.go` — it tries to decompress those chunks, starting with `all.in` and then trying to decompress chunks `0` and `1` step by step.

An attempt to decode `all.in` (`func all()`) somewhat succeeds, at least decompressed data is the same, but zlib reader returns error `flate: corrupt input before offset 446`.

When trying real-life scenario of decompressing chunk by chunk (`func stream()`), zlib reader decodes first chunk with expected data, but returning an error `flate: corrupt input before offset 32`, and subsequent attempt to decode chunk `1` fails completely.

### The question

Is it possible to use go's `zlib` package in some kind of "streaming" mode which is suited for scenario like this? Maybe I am using it incorrectly?

If not, what is the workaround? Also it would be interesting to know, why is that so — is it by design? Is it just not implemented yet? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that error is saying that the data at an offset after your input is corrupt. That is because of the way your are reading from the files:

```golang
    buf := make([]byte, 100000)
    n, readErr := f.Read(buf)
    if readErr != nil {
        log.Fatalf("readErr=%v\n", readErr)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Read bytes, n=%v\n", n)

    buffer := bytes.NewBuffer(buf)
    zlibReader, zlibErr := zlib.NewReader(buffer)
    if zlibErr != nil {
        log.Fatalf("zlibErr=%v\n", zlibErr)
    }
```

`buf := make([]byte, 100000)` will make a slice of 100000 bytes, all of them 0. But you are only reading 443 bytes in the case of `all.in`. Since you never shorten the slice, the reader will encounter a few thousand zeros after the valid data and conclude it is corrupt. That is why you get output and an error.

As for streaming. In the case of a TCP/UDP connection you should be able to just pass the connection which is a `io.Reader` to the `zlib.NewReader`. To simulate the same I used an [io.Pipe](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Pipe) in the modified code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/zlib"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"

    otherzlib "github.com/4kills/go-zlib"
)

func main() {
    all()
    stream()

    // Alas it hangs :(
    // otherZlib()
}

func all() {
    fmt.Println("==== RUNNING DECOMPRESSION OF all.in")
    fmt.Println("")

    buf, readErr := os.ReadFile("./chunks/all.in")
    if readErr != nil {
        log.Fatalf("readErr=%v\n", readErr)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Read bytes, n=%v\n", len(buf))

    buffer := bytes.NewBuffer(buf)
    zlibReader, zlibErr := zlib.NewReader(buffer)
    if zlibErr != nil {
        log.Fatalf("zlibErr=%v\n", zlibErr)
    }

    out := new(bytes.Buffer)
    written, copyErr := io.Copy(out, zlibReader)
    if copyErr != nil {
        log.Printf("copyErr=%v\n", copyErr)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Written bytes, n=%v, out:\n%v\n", written, out.String())
    fmt.Println("")
}

func stream() {
    fmt.Println("==== RUNNING DECOMPRESSION OF SEPARATE CHUNKS")
    fmt.Println("")

    pRead, pWrite := io.Pipe()
    go func() {
        buf, readErr := os.ReadFile("./chunks/0.in")
        if readErr != nil {
            log.Fatalf("readErr=%v\n", readErr)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Read 0 bytes, n=%v\n", len(buf))

        written0, copy0Err := io.Copy(pWrite, bytes.NewBuffer(buf))
        if copy0Err != nil {
            log.Printf("copy0Err=%v\n", copy0Err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Written compressed bytes, n0=%v", written0)

        buf, readErr = os.ReadFile("./chunks/1.in")
        if readErr != nil {
            log.Fatalf("read1Err=%v\n", readErr)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Read 1 bytes, n=%v\n", len(buf))

        written1, copy1Err := io.Copy(pWrite, bytes.NewBuffer(buf))
        if copy1Err != nil {
            log.Printf("copy1Err=%v\n", copy1Err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Written compressed bytes, n1=%v", written1)

        pWrite.Close()
    }()

    zlibReader, zlibErr := zlib.NewReader(pRead)
    if zlibErr != nil {
        log.Fatalf("zlibErr=%v\n", zlibErr)
    }

    out := new(bytes.Buffer)
    written2, copy2Err := io.Copy(out, zlibReader)
    if copy2Err != nil {
        log.Printf("copy2Err=%v\n", copy2Err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Written decompressed bytes, n0=%v, out:\n%v\n", written2, out.String())

    fmt.Println("")
}
```

With this code I get no errors from `stream()` but I still get a `copyErr=unexpected EOF` error from `all()`, looks like the `all.in` is missing checksum data at the end, but I figure that is just an accident.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
- With debugging I've reached the same conclusion about slice sizes.
As for EOF, that is actually what io.Copy does, it should not be used here, instead it is better to use zlibReader.Read(). 

As for checksums, it is expected, as far as I understand, in streaming mode.

As for pipe, in real-life scenario it is a bit more difficult — the stream does not start as compressed initially, it gets compressed after server/client negotiation, so zlib reader cannot read conn from the start.

Answer (score 0):

With careful debugging I was able to see that I have incorrectly passed too large buffer slices which lead to incorrect input buffers being fed to decompression.

Also, it is important not to use `io.Copy`, which leads to EOF on buffer which stops everything, and instead to use just zlibReader.Read(), which will decompress everything that is currently in buffer now.

I've updated the code so it now works as expected.