# Decoding chunks of a zlib stream from websocket

Tags: go, zlib, gorilla

I am trying to decode chunks from a zlib-stream compressed websocket (discord). I am using gorilla websocket.

My current code:

```
if messageType == websocket.BinaryMessage {
    z, err := zlib.NewReader(bytes.NewBuffer(premsg))
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("Error creating zlib reader:", err)
        return
    }

    message, err = ioutil.ReadAll(z)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("Error reading zlib reader:", err)
        return
    }

    err3 := z.Close()
    if err3 != nil {
        logger.Error("Error closing zlib:", err)
    }
}
```

this obviously fails because the chunks don't have headers.
Are there any packages or ways to do this with compress/zlib?

Comment: Does this help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70536980?